# swt table: how to dis-select the row when the mouse is not focus on the table?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on swt table. My question here is, how do I loss the focus/ dis-select the row, when my mouse is clicking somewhere else?

```
table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
         TableItem[] selection = table.getSelection();
         deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
         if(selection.length!=0){
             deleteButton.setEnabled(true);
         }
}});
```

As the UI attachment here, only when user select something in the table, then the deletebutton would be enabled, then user can go ahead and delete that item. My problem here is, once the user select an item, there's no way to dis-select it unless user deletes the item. Is there a way for me to loss the selection whenever user is clicking on some other area on the UI? I know there's a thing called "table.deselectAll()", but I don't know where should I include it. When I click on somewhere else on the UI, the handleEvent just don't get triggered at all. Really appreciate for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a listener for the `SWT.FocusOut` event which will be notified when the table loses the focus.

Comment: where should I define this event? is it like this     "table.addListener(SWT.FocusOut,tableListner)" ? For some reason, after I defined this event, my delete button is always disabled :( Do I miss something here?

Comment: Yes it is just another listener.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying me! I think my question here is, since the "delete" button is not part of table, when the selection.size()>1 then user should be able to do the delete here. So if I add the "table.addListener(SWT.FocusOut,tableListner)" event to the table, which is doing table.deselectAll(), then the delete function would never work.
Can I set the focusOut listener on the composite, instead of the table? is there a better suggestion? thanks again!

Comment: Possibly, I think you are go to have to experiment a bit. I would say that it is not usual to do all this, mostly the selection and enablement are left untouched when focus moves to some other control.

Comment: Ya, that's what I was thinking, but unfortunately, in windows server 2008, for some reason, once user left the table, and clicks on some other control, the selection disappears, but the "delete"button still remains enabled, which might causes the confusion. (But it does what you said on windows7 though, so this is kinda frustrated... )